# Google Earth Plugin in Metro App

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-metro, winrt-xaml, google-earth-plugin

I've been Googling around but have not found a definitive answer. Can I or will I be able to embed the Google Earth Plugin within a custom Windows 8 Metro application?

Our current application uses a WinForms WebBrowser to display the plugin, and I understand that WinForms will not be supported for Metro apps. Yes, we can run our current app on Windows 8 as a desktop application, but I am interested in a Metro app.

It looks like a XAML WebView might be what we need to display the plugin, but some of what I've read indicates that the plugin will not work within a Metro app because the browsing is "plugin free". Any confirmation/further explanation of this for custom Metro apps?

Thanks!

Comment: The default browser control have no installed plugins but you could try to inherit from the control and add the needed extensions.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible as...

> ...the new Windows UI browsing experience doesn't support Microsoft
>   ActiveX or any other binary extensibility.

See [Plugins and ActiveX controls (Windows)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ie/hh920753%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

This is because the whole idea of the 'metro' version of IE is that it should only display, standards-based, plug-in free websites.

You can read more about the reasoning behind this and a fuller explanation of the new browser in [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh968248%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).